# Enthought Mayavi TVTK Scene no display

Tags: python, vtk, enthought, mayavi

I am using Enthough Canopy on Ubuntu 14.04.
I installed mayavi & VTK through Canopy GUI.

The following example shows a TVTK Scene with no display.

```
from mayavi import mlab
mlab.test_contour3d()
```